# Regex to detect an odd number of consecutive quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

If a string contains a single quote `"`, I need to replace it with double quotes `""`. However, sometimes a valid double-quote can be followed by a single quote, eg. `"""`, which just needs another quote added to the end. If I use a standard replace, eg. `replace('"', '""')`, all the quotes are turned into doubles, of course, not just the odd one.

What I need is to find any odd number of consecutive quotes (including a single one on its own) and simply add another quote onto the end. Eg. `"` becomes `""`, and `"""` becomes `""""`.

Is there a regex replace in JavaScript which can accomplish this?

Comment: I've come up with the following, which uses look-behind/ahead, but JavaScript doesn't seem to support it: `((?<!")(?:"")*"(?!"))` replace with `$1"` http://regex101.com/r/mX9xI7

Comment: This is a nice programming problem and it's pretty tricky to get right, so +1.  _However_, this task is precisely what one would do to escape double quotes when writing CSV.  If so, you'd want to use an existing CSV library rather that rolling this on your own, I would think.

Comment: Correct, JavaScript does not support negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the quotes consecutive? Unless I've misunderstood your requirement, this would work...

```
str = str.replace(/\"\"?/g, '""')
```

**Explanation:** Matches a single quote, optionally followed by another quote, and replaces one/both with two quotes.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aR6p2/

Or alternatively, if it's just a matter of appending a quote when there's an odd number of quotes in a string...

```
  var count = str.split('"').length - 1
  str = str + (count % 2 == 0 ? '' : '"')
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to solve, though I was hoping for a single regex expression, as opposed to procedural js.

Comment: Well, the regex he is using is ""?  and the replacement string is  ""

Comment: Sorry, brain fizz. First method confirmed. http://regex101.com/r/zM5kL5. Great answer, so simple!

Comment: +1 for a good solution, but a little difficult to find the actual answer in the demo code. Better to provide the answer explicitly (e.g. `s.replace(/\"\"?/g, '""')`, then the demo that uses it. Also worth noting that it depends on greedy matching.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for the feedback. Updated the answer to be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
var str = '"" """" """ """""';
var re = /([^"]|^)"("")*(?!")/g;
console.log(str.replace(re, '$1(quotes)')); // '"" """" (quotes) (quotes)'
```

What that does is the following:

- it matches a non-quote - or the start of the entered string - first, and stores it in the first capturing group
- then it matches one double-quote
- then a group of 2 double-quotes, for any amount of times (0 or more)
- it then checks if the next character is a non-quote, but without actually matching it.
- This is then replaced by the value captured by the first capturing group (the non-quote), and the string `(quotes)`.

Basically, it just replaces any odd amount of double-quotes with `(quotes)`.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eV4tE2)

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not sure how to use this to add another quote onto the end of the string of odd quotes that is matched. If I replace `$1(quotes)` with `$1"`, all I get is a single quote.

Comment: To explain what I mean, see: http://regex101.com/r/rZ5zA1. Do I have the wrong idea regarding the replace? Pls see my comment under the question for an example of what I'm after (my solution works in php flavour but not js flavour).

Comment: @ingredient_15939 So did you mean to do http://regex101.com/r/hL5aA8 or http://regex101.com/r/nQ2lH6 then?

Comment: regex101.com/r/hL5aA8, yes. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a crazy regular expression that will do that, but to keep myself from going crazy I'd do this.

```
str = str.replace(/[^"]("+)/, function(match, group1){
   if((group1.length % 2) === 1 || group1.length === 1){
      return group1+'"';
   }
   return group1;
});
```